# How can I combine multiple textures so that they blend together?

Tags: texture-painting

I've seen many examples of this, and I can't seem to find the answer anywhere online. The best I've been able to do is, in Texture Paint, edit the actual texture image file.

But what if I could simply unwrap a texture as terrain, and be able to mix, say, a rocky texture with a grassy one, and have one blend into the other smoothly, rather than an abrupt edge?

I've seen this executed beautifully before, and if anyone could give me any insights, I'd really appreciate it! I feel like it's the missing piece that would improve my creations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The traditional way to do this was vertex colors. The amount of (say) red would be the blend factor between the textures. Use a node setup like this.

[image: Blender between two textures; the factor is the red channel of vertex color]

Set the 3D View to Material preview and switch to Vertex Paint mode. Paint black where you want the first texture to show through, and red where you want the second.

[image: Painting in vertex paint mode]

Alternatively, you could use a third texture to control the blend amount and paint it in Texture Paint mode.

Comment: To give you finer control on coarse meshes, you could also use an image texture instead of the vertex colors as mask. With a sufficiently feathered brush, you can achieve smooth blendig as well.

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much! I knew there had to be a way; I've seen it done so many times. I spent so long trying to experiment with different possible solutions, and it turns out to be much smoother than I thought.