# How do I make a texture gradient?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I want to make a ground for a forest. But it's boring when it's only one seemless tiled texture. So I thought i can use multiple textures, but how can I combine them? I want some gradients between each of them. A bit of dirt, a bit of grass, a bit of leaves etc. Maybe with projection painting, but then I have no hightmap of the whole ground texture. How can I handle this?

Comment: Maybe https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/211515/how-can-i-combine-multiple-textures-so-that-they-blend-together

Comment: Scurest gives an answer with Vertex Paint, which work fine if you have enough topology, if it's not the case, as pointed out by Haarigertroll under this answer, you can use an image texture