# How to make a wet sand effect? Island Scene

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I wanted to darken the sand around the island on the beach near the ocean to create an illusion of a wet sand. I tried to do it using texture paitings, but I don’t know how to do it. I use a poliigon texture for the sand.

This is how it looks right now:

[image]

This is how I want it to look:

[image]

This is what I get when I try to paint over it:

[image]

Does anyone has any idea achieve this wet sand effect? I would be so extremely helpful for any help!

Comment: More than making it darker, you need to add reflection, gloss,but not too much, also specular

Comment: In reality I just want a very subtle darker color around the water and that's it. But again, I have no idea how to paint it on the Island:(

Comment: animation or still?

Comment: @AllenSimpson animation would be nice but I suppose it's more complicated, so I'll be very happy with a still!

Comment: Try _Vertex Paint_, not _Texture Paint_ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/211515/how-can-i-combine-multiple-textures-so-that-they-blend-together

Comment: So I'd have to combine a wet sand texture with the sand texture I'm using and "paint" the wet sand with vertex painting, yes?

Comment: @taiyo okay I tried it and that was the solution, thank you so much!

Comment: @Biers glad it helped!